# Dimension de la imagen en una galeria de materialize CSS

Tags: materialize

Hola amigos  tengo el siguiente problema tengo una galeria con el framework materialize CSS estoy intentando hacer que las animaciones se vean completamente pero no me las muestra completamente todas ?

alguien sabe porque ?

Mi codigo de la galeria:

```html
<div id="test1" class="col s12">

 <div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img id="active" src="img/inicio.jpg"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Lovi Acabados</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3"><div class="container"><span class="write"></span>
</div></h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/2.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption left-align">
          <h3>Las mejores piedras de sonora</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Necesitas decorar tu casa, somos los expertos.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/3.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption right-align">
          <h3>Virgenes de Guadalupe</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Tenemos las mejores estatuas de la virgen de Guadalupe hechas a mano por nuestros expertos.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/5.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Amas a los animales !</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Tenemos las mejores esculturas de animales decorativos para tu Hogar.</h5>
        </div>
              <li>
        <img src="img/6.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Nos has decorado tu casa!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Decora tu casa con las mejores piedras de sonora.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="img/7.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Dale un toque unico a tu casa</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Lovi Acabados tenemos las mejores decoracion del estado.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="img/8.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Dale Paz y alegria a tu casa!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">En Lovi Acabados tenemos para ti las virgenes de guadalupe talladas a mano.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="img/9.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Dale elegancia a tu casa!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Dale elegancia a tu casa con las mejores esculturas de piedra para tu casa.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="img/logo.png"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Y Muchos Mas Productos!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Lovi Acabados es la mejor.</h5>
        
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Necesito hacer que las imagenes se vean completas pero solo se ve un pedaso de la imagen alguien sabe como hacer que sea vea completa.

Answer (score -2):

a lo que entendí sobre tu pregunta

1- si no logras ver todas las imágenes con el `slider` es por la barra de navegación, es decir esta sobre tu `slider`, lo que necesitas es ajustar `"position"` del valor "`absolute`" a "`relative`",

otro camino no tan "pro" es ajustar `"margin-top"` hasta que se vea la imagen completa, espero haber sido de ayuda.